# systemd stops restarting service

Tags: systemd

**tl;dr:** systemd restarts a crashing service for days and then suddenly stops.

I've got a service configured as follows:

```
[Unit]

[Service]
Restart=always
RestartSec=2
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node --max-old-space-size=4096 /home/somewhere/something.js
StandardOutput=null
StandardError=null
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This code crashes sometimes (1-2 times a day), hence the need to `Restart=always`. Yet once in a while this service doesn't get restarted and here's the output of `systemctl status`:

```
   Loaded: loaded (/home/somewhere/something-systemd.service; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-12-04 10:10:46 CET; 7s ago
  Process: 333 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node --max-old-space-size=4096 /home/somewhere/something.js (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 333 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Is there a mistake in my configuration? How do I force systemd to restart a service no matter what?

Comment: Could it be possible that node is running out of allocated memory or another resource given that it crashes in operation? Have you tried running the application without systemd for any length of time?

Comment: Nope; see the answer below, this was the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StartLimitIntervalSec=` belongs to the [Unit] section. See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#

> ### [Unit] Section Options
>
> #### StartLimitIntervalSec=, StartLimitBurst=
>
> Configure unit start rate limiting. **By default, units which are started more than 5 times within 10 seconds are not permitted to start any more times until the 10 second interval ends.** ...

Like this:

```
[Unit]
StartLimitIntervalSec=0    

[Service]
Restart=always
RestartSec=2
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node --max-old-space-size=4096 /home/somewhere/something.js
StandardOutput=null
StandardError=null
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: That is not necessarily true. See what happens when I add StartLimitInterval into [Unit] Section: Unknown lvalue 'StartLimitInterval' in section 'Unit'

Comment: It is because they changed that to StartLimitIntervalSec from StartLimitInterval in version 230, while Ubuntu 16.04 ships with 229. 

But indeed this is the correct answer.

Comment: @TomaszPapir-Zwierz It is true, but it might be different if you have an older version, yes. I forgot to mention it, but then again, people should always read the manual for their version of a software :)